# How to center android application attributes in visual studio?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

I have made a login activity in visual studio and everything seems fine in the designer tab. But when exported to a physical device, everything is off centred. How can I fix this issue?

Heres the XML for the activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/carbon"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="login"
        android:textSize="35px"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="280px"
        android:layout_marginTop="80px"
        android:layout_marginRight="280px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="500px"
        android:src="@drawable/email1"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="97dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:alpha=".9"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="97dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:alpha=".9"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="70px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120px"
        android:layout_marginTop="415px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="415px"
        android:layout_marginRight="120px"
        android:src="@drawable/email"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120px"
        android:layout_marginTop="590px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="415px"
        android:layout_marginRight="120px"
        android:src="@drawable/key"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:textColor="#ffb702"
        android:text="Login"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" 
        android:textSize="50px"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="335dp"
        android:textColor="#ffb702"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textColorLink="#ffb702"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" 
        android:textSize="30px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

StackOverflow isn't letting me post this question without adding more details so now I will add random garbage. fjsfkdsfkshfksgklsjdlksdjlfklsdjfgjfkljflskfjslkjdfksjfskljfdkljfslkfjsfjsklfjslkfjsklfjslkfjdslkfjslkdjfslkfjslkfjdslkfjslkfjslkjfdslkjfslkfjslkdjfslkjflkjfsfjsdlkjflskjfjlskjfksjfksjfskfslfjldkjfsklfjlksdjfslkfjslkfjslkfjskfjskfjskjfsklfjslkjfldkjfldkjfdlkjflksdjfslkjfslkfjkldfjslkfjdlksj

the image below shows what happens after the app is launched on a real phone

[image: everything is missaligned]

Comment: What is the very small anomaly in the image to the left of the "Login" text?

Comment: @RonBeyer that anomaly is actually two very small icons stacked on top of each other. they were supposed to be next to the "email" and "password" editText fields

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add the

> android:layout_gravity="center"

property in the elements you want to center. I noticed that all elements are stacked on the top of each other, maybe you can use a LinearLayout instead, not a RelativeLayout. Also can try a ConstraintLayout, which has a lot of features, and Google provides very good docs and examples [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- Don't use margins and fixed values to align elements
- Using a `ConstraintLayout` is recommended
- Editing the `XML`-layout directly in text is usually easier than using a WYSIWYG editor after you got used to it
- Don't use `px` ever! Use `dp` and `sp` instead. `sp` is for text sizes
- If you need different layouts for landscape or big / small screens, create [alternative layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts)

You are using fixed values for margins to align your elements inside the `RelativeLayout`. This leads to a design that will only look good on a specific screen size: Your preview in Visual Studio.

Example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:text="login"
    />
```

The `Button` will always be aligned by getting a margin of 250dp from the top and 65dp from the left. The value doesn't change. No matter if you execute your app on a small device with a width of 300dp or a big tablet with a width of 1200dp. The button will always be 65dp away from the left screen border.

You need to remove most of the fixed margins and align the elements in relation to each other to create flexible layouts ([see Google's recommendation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#flexible-layout)). You should also stop using `px` altogether and just use `dp` for dimensions and `sp` for text sizes. As other users suggest, it is highly recommended to use a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

Comment: is there a quick way to switch between layouts? i tried to switch between them but all elements get removed and id have to start over